# AVD in Android Studio on Mac is showing buttons as plain text

Tags: android, macos, button, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have just started using Android Studio on Mac. The buttons I have created are showing as text on the AVD. Can anyone help me to fix this?

[image: image of my avd showing buttons and edittext]

Thank you.  It looks correct while rendering in the Design window.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="188dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="67dp"
    android:onClick="speakText"
    android:text="@string/Speak"
    android:clickable="true"
     />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="81dp"
    android:ems="10" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/buttonSpeaker"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button1"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: can you post the xml

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the material design. You can inherit you theme in `style.xml` like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Or overide global button style like this
in `AppTheme`:

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/customButtonStyle</item>`
```

and in style.xml

```
 <style name="customButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <!-- Customize your button style here. -->
 </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I already have style.xml with the statement in it. It is not working. Is there something I am missing.

Comment: Show you layout xml and style.xml, please.

Comment: I still can't figure why AppTheme is not working like it does in the Design window. but thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I changed the theme to Theme.dialog and it looks different.

Comment: Glad that helped. Styles - an interesting thing) Maybe Material is default theme in you avd..